# UIWebView to take content height iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview, uiwebview, header

I have a `TableViewController` with a header, footer and a reusable cell. Following are my contents in the above views :-

Header :

```
--Label
--Label
--WebView
```

Cell -  `normal dynamic data`

Footer :

```
--TextField 
--Button
```

[image]

My motive is to make the whole view scrollable, disabling the scroll on the `WebView` and `UITableViewCell`. My issue is with the WebView. I want it to take the height of the content and there should be no scrolling. But right now, the webview only shows up in the denoted space with a scroll which messes up my UI. How do I make the WebView and the header resize according to the WebView content?

Answer (score -1):

i have done this trick in Scroll View. I have disabled WebView Scrolling and bounces from xib.

Then load data in webview and get its content height in webViewDidfinishLoad method:

use below code as i have done for ScrollView, but you to manage fot TableView by its index. Assign Webview.tag = indexPath.section

get webview instance by its tag it.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGFloat contentHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    self.webPage.frame = CGRectMake(self.webPage.frame.origin.x, self.webPage.frame.origin.y, self.webPage.frame.size.width, webPage);
    //after this assign your tableview header height here
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. What isschCircleDescWeb here?